# Remix vs Truffle project in VSCode

Tags: truffle, remix

I do this post to ask your methodologies and customs when developing smart contracts. Between Remix + Ganache and Truffle Project + Ganache.

What is more comfortable for you?
Why is one better than another?

Nose, any kind of doubts or clarifications that can be provided are welcome.

A big greeting !!

Answer (score 2):

I´d rather a truffle project because I can add tests for my smart contract.

Comment: Yea that´s so positive +1 truffle